# Symmetry of a Dot with functions with arguments

Tags: replacement, conditional

Seemingly an easy question, but I'm trying to avoid using a straight replacement rule.

As an example, I could take a term like

```
p[i].p[j]-p[j].p[i]
```

where this dot product is symmetric, and so should evaluate to zero.

I'm trying to avoid using a replacement rule, since I'm trying to generalise. 
I have tried using `Signature` and `Sort` to try and automatically swap the latter term by canonical sorting, but to no avail.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

EDIT: 
I think I will extend my question to get the exact answer I am searching for. I'm using a recursion relation to generate a load of terms, which involve these dot products.

I am looking to basically express any dot product which is has a signature of -1 from canonical order as the reversed order, to lead to some nice cancellations:

For any choice of `i,j`, I'm looking to get something like:

```
If[Signature[p[i_].p[j_]]==-1, Return[p[j].p[i]]]
```

Can this be easily achieved?

EDIT2:
I think the answer lies in `ConditionalReplace`. Let me try muddling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce):

```
TensorReduce[
    p[i].p[j] - p[j].p[i],
    Assumptions -> (p[i] | p[j]) ∈ Vectors[d]
]
```

> 0

Comment: I like the look of that. Could you explain why it works? Could I not assume vectors in the original dot product somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I threw a few people off by saying that I didn't want a replacement rule, but what I was really trying to avoid was a simplistic version, i.e

```
//.{p[b_].p[a_]:> p[a].[b]}
```

I managed to avert this by using a conditional rule, so that it only replaces the terms which are out of canonical order. I am satisfied with:

```
p[a_].p[b_]/;Signature[p[a].p[b]]==-1:>p[b].p[a]
```

somewhere in a replacement rule sequence. Thank you to Carl for his suggestion; it put me on the right track of assumptions!